# Java local classes and interfaces

Tags: java, interface, local-class

I was wondering if the next thing is possible for implementation:

Lets say I've got 2 interfaces while each one of them has 1 function header.
**For example, iterface1 has function g(...) and interface2 has function f(...)**

Now, I make a class and declaring that this class is implementing these 2 interfaces.
In the class I try doing the next thing:

I start implementing function g(...) and in it's implementation I make a local class that implements interface2 and I add to this class the implementation of f(...).

Comment: Rather than words, sample code will be invaluable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. I am picturing something like this:

```
interface Interface1
{
    public void g();
}

interface Interface2
{
    public void f();
}

class MyClass implements Interface1, Interface2
{
    @Override
    public void g()
    {
        class InnerClass implements Interface2
        {
            @Override
            public void f()
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is that what you meant?

In this case, the answer is no. The inner class (`InnerClass`) works fine, but it doesn't count as an implementation of `f` for the outer class. You would still need to implement `f` in `MyClass`:

```
MyClass.java:11: MyClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method
f() in Interface2
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've meant. Thank you!

Comment: That's exactly how I understood the question - and no, it's not "legal" (meaning that `MyClass` still has to provide an implementation for `f`, unless it's abstract)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is legal. However a class does not implement an interface because an inner class implements it. The class must implement the interface explicitly or declare itself as abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's legal. In the example you've given, your class should implement all methods of both interfaces, and your local class should implement all methods of interface2.